# Solve the equation: $(9x^2+6x-8)\sqrt{3x+2}+6x+23=27x^2+3\sqrt{10+3x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the equation:

$(9x^2+6x-8)\sqrt{3x+2}+6x+23=27x^2+3\sqrt{10+3x}$

---

I used wolframalpha.com and got only solution $x=-\dfrac{1}{3}$.

And this is my try:

> Condition: $x\ge-\dfrac{2}{3}$.
>
> The equation is equivalent to:
>
> $\quad(3x+1)^2\sqrt{3x+2}+9-9\sqrt{3x+2}=27x^2-6x-5+3\sqrt{10+3x}-9$
>
> $\Leftrightarrow (3x+1)^2\sqrt{3x+2}-\dfrac{9(3x+1)}{1+\sqrt{3x+2}}=(3x+1)(9x-5)+\dfrac{3(3x+1)}{\sqrt{10+3x}+3}$
>
> $\Leftrightarrow (3x+1)\left[(3x+1)\sqrt{3x+2}-\dfrac{9}{1+\sqrt{3x+2}}-9x+5-\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10+3x}+3}\right]=0$

But I can't prove that $(3x+1)\sqrt{3x+2}-\dfrac{9}{1+\sqrt{3x+2}}-9x+5-\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10+3x}+3}>0$.

So, who can help me solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the polynomial that you get by multiplying by the three conjugates is 
$$59049x^{10}-118098x^9+164025x^8-236196x^7 -441774x^6+133164x^5+373086x^4-390636x^3 -193203x^2+141054x+50641=0$$
This has four real zeros, including $x=-1/3$, but those would include negative signs for the square-roots.